# Images aren't displaying.. Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, image, swing

I am trying to make this program that has two images that move in the straight line and when they read the end of frame, they turn their direction... But the thing is, the images aren't appearing on the screen idk why.. Here is my code for Actor class

```
public class Actor {



    private Image img;
    private int x,y,width,height;
    private final int RIGHT=1,LEFT=-1;
    private byte direction=RIGHT;
    public Actor(Image img, int x,int  y, int width, int height){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;

    }
    public Image getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public void movement(int frameWidth){
        setX(getX()+direction);
        if(getX()<0) direction= RIGHT;
        if(getX()>(frameWidth-width)) direction= LEFT;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and here is my main class:

```
public class game extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    private int framewidth=1000;
    private int frameheight=1500;
    Image image= new ImageIcon("pics/buffy.png").getImage();
    Image image2= new ImageIcon("pics/buffythelayer.jpg").getImage();
    private Thread thread;
    private int picX=100;
    private int c=1;
    private int xSpeed=3;
    private int xFly=1;
    private int yFly=100;
    private Actor greenCar,pinkCar;
    public game(){
        setBounds(100,100,framewidth,frameheight);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        thread= new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        greenCar=new Actor(image,30,70,98,40);
        pinkCar=new Actor(image2,400,70,98,40);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(xFly, yFly, 10, 10);
        g.drawImage(greenCar.getImg(), greenCar.getX(), greenCar.getY(), null);
        g.drawImage(pinkCar.getImg(), pinkCar.getX(), pinkCar.getY(), null);
        if(c==2){
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillOval(100, 200, 150, 200);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new game();

    }

    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
            xFly++;
            greenCar.movement(framewidth);
            pinkCar.movement(framewidth);
            /*if(picX>280){
                xSpeed=-xSpeed;
                picX=picX+xSpeed;
                c=2;
            }
            if(picX>=100){
                xSpeed=3;
            picX=picX+xSpeed;


            }*/

            repaint();
            try{
                thread.sleep(13);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){

            }

        }
        }

}
```

Comment: Move  `setVisible(true); ` to the end of the constructor. It should be the last thing you do: you make the frame visible once everything is set up. Next step would be to learn [How to do custom painting properly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Comment: `Image image= new ImageIcon("pics/buffy.png").getImage();` Have you researched this ***at all?*** This same problem must come up every single day. Twice or three times on a busy day.

Comment: `while(true)`, `Thread.sleep()` overriding `paint()`, not calling `super.paint(g)`, calling `setBounds()` not respecting the EDT... learn how to use a Swing Timer, how to do custom painting and to use layout managers and also how to place your program on the EDT

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the problem. When you run the code below, you set the last value, the ImageObserver, to null.

```
g.drawImage(greenCar.getImg(), greenCar.getX(), greenCar.getY(), null);
g.drawImage(pinkCar.getImg(), pinkCar.getX(), pinkCar.getY(), null);
```

Instead, you should write it like this:

```
g.drawImage(greenCar.getImg(), greenCar.getX(), greenCar.getY(), this);
g.drawImage(pinkCar.getImg(), pinkCar.getX(), pinkCar.getY(), this);
```

Therefore, the JFrame is the object that is notified as the image loads and can be drawn on the screen correctly.

If that's not the case, then you should add super.paint(g) to your paint method.

Your paint(g) method should look like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.fillRect(xFly, yFly, 10, 10);
    g.drawImage(greenCar.getImg(), greenCar.getX(), greenCar.getY(), this);
    g.drawImage(pinkCar.getImg(), pinkCar.getX(), pinkCar.getY(), this);
    if(c==2){
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillOval(100, 200, 150, 200);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: well only one pic appears.. the second one doesn't :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you run thread before you construct the car object, so

creat object first, the run the thread

```
    greenCar=new Actor(image,30,70,98,40);
    pinkCar=new Actor(image2,400,70,98,40);
    thread.start();
```

and you forget set image in Actor constructor

```
    public Actor(Image img, int x,int  y, int width, int height){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
    this.img = img;

}
```

Comment: only one pic appear.. second one doesnt

Comment: Check your file name, path, extention